# Microsoft Graph API: PATCH to update metadata of a file in DocumentLibrary results in 409 response; Code: resourceModified

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using Microsoft Graph SDK to upload file to SharePoint's DocumentLibrary (..DocumentSet) and then update the metadata. The code used to upload file and update metadata is as below,

```
var created = await _graphServiceClientFactory.GetClient().Drives[driveId].Root.ItemWithPath($"{id}/{fileName}").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
if (created != null)
{
    await _graphServiceClientFactory.GetClient().Drives[driveId].Root.ItemWithPath($"{id}/{fileName}").ListItem.Fields.Request()
               .UpdateAsync(new FieldValueSet { AdditionalData = dataDictionary });
}
```

The upload of file works consistently, however, intermittently the call to update metadata is resulting in 409 error.  I am not sure why the 409 error is thrown, the file is being created and based on the success response the metadata is being updated (sequential call).  Error returned from the patch call is as below, the metadata being updated is limited to few of custom columns in SharePoint's document library.

> Code: resourceModified Message: The resource has changed since the
> caller last read it; usually an eTag mismatch

What could be cause of this error? How to resolve the same?

Comment: Hi, can you show the code of the dataDictionary? Have you inserted in the @odata.type?

Comment: @E.Peracchia: Thanks for responding. The dataDictionary contains key/value pairs that are whitelisted, and '@odata.type' column is not part of the whitelist.  The REST API service which uses Graph SDK acts as a integration layer, and consumer application makes calls to them.  Once in a while for the similar json payload (same column names) 409 exception is thrown.

Comment: You could try this: 
AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                            {
                                { "TemplateId@odata.type", "Edm.String" },
                                { "TemplateId", template.TemplateId },
                                { "Title@odata.type", "Edm.String" },
                                { "Title", template.Oggetto}
                            }


template.templateId and template.Oggetto are attributes of an object i created. I map them with TemplateId and Title ( two columns in my sp).
It worked for me.
Hope it helps